# Youtube API V3 - How to get filename from fileDetails

Tags: php, youtube-api

I'm brand new to APIs so please excuse what is probably a long and stupid question.  Can I modify this code I got from this sample script - https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/php#update_a_video_by_adding_new_tags - to return the original name of the uploaded file for one of my company's videos?  Note: I have already modified the linked script to remove the updating of tags (i.e. I just had it print the video id and the current tags to test that I had the Oauth2 working and I did - so, I got that far at least.)

```
// Call the API's videos.list method to retrieve the video resource.
$listResponse = $youtube->videos->listVideos("snippet",
    array('id' => $videoId));
```

I was thinking that changing to "snippet" to "fileDetails" is what I need. If so, then how do then extract just the original filename from $listResponse?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the world of Google Development.  Lets look at the documentation a little for [videos.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list).

If you check under response you will notice that it returns an array of video resources click on that and the documentation will take you to [Videos resource representation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#resource-representation) as you can see there is lots of fun stuff here.   Under snippet you find title.

> snippet.title string
>  The video's title. The property value has a
>   maximum length of 100 characters and may contain all valid UTF-8
>   characters except < and >. You must set a value for this property if
>   you call the videos.update method and are updating the snippet part of
>   a video resource.

On the main videos.list documentation page you will find some examples of how to use it with PHP.   Here is a hunk of the first one I think you will like.

```
// Display the list of matching videos.
foreach ($videosResponse['items'] as $videoResult) {
      $videos .= sprintf('<li>%s </li>',
          $videoResult['snippet']['title']);
    }
```

Googles documentation is very useful always check it.

Comment: Thank you! I've tried looking at Google documentation, but it's really hard for a newbie like me to understand where to find what I'm looking for.  But, thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction!